# Java HTTP POST request with JSON

Tags: java, json, http, post

After running the post request with JSON I have HTTP Error 400 Bad request.
I think the problem is in the JSON string but I do not now how to fix it.

```
package Curl;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Http_Con {

    private static HttpURLConnection connection;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Http_Con connection = new Http_Con();
        //call the getRequest method
        connection.GetRequest();
        //call the postRequest
        connection.PostRequest();

    }
    public void GetRequest() {
        BufferedReader reader;
        String lines;
        StringBuilder responseContent = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            //set the url
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.104:4041/iot/devices");
            //open the connection
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //set the request method and timeout
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
            //set request properties(in this case headers)
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Fiware-Service", " myHome");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Fiware-ServicePath", "/environment");

            //get the response code(200 should be OK)
            int status = connection.getResponseCode();

            if (status > 299) {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
                while ((lines = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseContent.append(lines);
                }
                reader.close();
            } else {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                while ((lines = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseContent.append(lines);
                }
                reader.close();
            }
            //print the response content(result)
            System.out.println(responseContent.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void PostRequest() throws IOException {
        //set the url
        String url = "http://192.168.0.104:4041/iot/devices";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        //open the connection
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        //set the method type(POST OR GET)
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        //set hte request properties(headers etc.)
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Fiware-Service"," myHome");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Fiware-ServicePath","/environment");


        //make sure that will be able to write content to the connection output stream
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //Json formatted input string
        String jsonInputString = "{\n" +
            "    \"devices\": [\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"device_id\": \"sensor01\",\n" +
            "            \"entity_name\": \"LivingRoomSensor\",\n" +
            "            \"entity_type\": \"multiSensor\",\n" +
            "            \"attributes\": [\n" +
            "                  { \"object_id\": \"t\", \"name\": \"Temperature\", \"type\": \"celsius\" },\n" +
            "                  { \"object_id\": \"l\", \"name\": \"Luminosity\", \"type\": \"lumens\" }\n" +
            "            ]\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "}";

        try(OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()) {
            byte[] input = jsonInputString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);
        }

        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String responseLine = null;
            while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(responseLine.trim());
            }
            //print the result
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the api is not expecting "" ad json body for the post request so it's returning bad request, it's a bit weird for an api to expect an empty json string ad boy, it usually would either expect the body to be empty or to have some data. Can you provide more info about the api you are trying to call?

Answer (score 0):

I Think you can use Fidder application to do something, which find Questions so fast. Due to 400 statusCode, Liking Cookie lost, params lost, request method lost .... trust think for you help！

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.